# self performSelector:withObject: afterDelay: does not call method

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an iPhone application where I'm trying to call particular method after certain delay. But the method is not getting called. I have no clue why its not getting called.

Here is my code

```
-(void)gettingCommentsList { //    some stuff....

    [self performSelector:@selector(callGetListInBackgroundMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0]; }

-(void)callGetListInBackgroundMethod {
    isFromthread =YES;


     NSLog(@"callGetListInBackground");
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Add code here to do background processing
        //
        //

        [self gettingCommentsList];
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Add code here to update the UI/send notifications based on the
            // results of the background processing

            [self.commentsTbl reloadData];
        });
    });



}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hold Alt key & hover mouse on method to check that method is identify or not. Otherwise call like `[self performSelector:@selector(callGetListInBackgroundMethod:)
               withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];`

Comment: are you sure that `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is actually called?

Comment: Yes I am sure that its getting called

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(callGetListInBackgroundMethod)
               withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4]; this method not called i am sure

Comment: try deleting project from organizer then clean and run.

Comment: It should call if you have declared your method in the same class. Please check by adding breakpoint in your method to see if its calling or not.

Comment: when i write [self callGetListInBackgroundMethod] the method is getting called but when i try to add delay by using performselector method its not calling that method

Comment: Is the problem occurring as I'm trying to call gettingCommentsList method using GCD and then calling performselector method

Comment: Why are you calling callGetListInBackgroundMethod from gettingCommentList and then gettingCommentList from dispatch_async in callGetListInBackgroundMethod?

Comment: what I am exactly doing is sending request using soap. And then parsing the response. After parsing I again try to call soap but in separate thread so that my application doesn't hangs. But I want to call the soap after particular time interval.

Comment: are you calling gettingCommentsList method or not .... if you don't call this method in first place then no perform selector will be set ...

Answer (score 3):

One potential problem is that timers do not prevent threads from exiting before the timer's fired. So if the run loop (of the thread which calls `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`) has no other source (work), it may not continue running for one second or more and the thread will exit before your timer fires (and your custom work is executed).

That's certainly possible *if* you schedule the timer on a secondary thread.

I suspect the reason for this design is because timers may be configured as recurring (or not) -- a lot of people would end up with 'zombie' threads because those recurring timers would never be invalidated. That problem could easily chew up a ton of system resources.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not calling [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling each method from the other -

In gettingCommentList, you call

```
[self performSelector:@selector(callGetListInBackgroundMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

and in callGetListInBackgroundMethod in dispatch_async you call

```
[self gettingCommentList];
```

Edit:

Try making the call just once and see if it works. If it does, it might be that you're not done with the first call before the second one begins, hence the problem. Let me know what happens.

Edit 2:

I tried your code. The problem is the the subsequent calls to gettingCommentList are in the background thread rather than the main thread. So I did this:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Add code here to do background processing
    //        
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self gettingCommentsList];
    });
});
```

and it works. But make sure you don't call the two functions continuously as this would make them run all the time, which I'm sure you don't really want :-)

Comment: what I am exactly doing is sending request using soap. And then parsing the response. After parsing I again try to call soap but in separate thread so that my application doesn't hangs. But I want to call the soap after particular time interval

Comment: But I want the call to gettingCommentsList method in background. If I call on main thread then my application will hang